# Css print : page margin conflicts with fixed title

Tags: css, printing

I am looking for a way to set a print-devoted css that shows a fixed title on every page.
Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to print this title nicely on the 2nd page, since it always "walks on " the table, ignoring declared body padding / margin ... though I am quite sure the *body* is not suited here, I couldn't find any working way.

Any idea?

```
<h2 id="tableTitle">Fixed title</h2>
<button class="noPrint" onclick="myFunction()">Print this table</button>
<table>...content fitting at least 2 pages ...</table>
```

...

```
body{
  margin-top:100px;
}
#tableTitle {                           
    position: fixed;
    top : 0;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jkLR/25/)